# Error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified after hosting to a web server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hosting, publish

I developed website  using Asp.Net MVC C#, and everything works  fine  locally on my pc in Visual Studio. After hosting the website to the server I got ***Error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified***. The error shows up when I try to login to the website, after I press the login button.
I think the problem is with automatically created authentication database **ASPNETDB.mdf** in **App_Data** folder and the **connection string** to that database. 
 I was searching and trying  different already published solutions before but I still can't solve the error.I tried different solutions to solve that in web.config, but unsucsessfully.

The solution I am looking is somewhere in configuring  my ASP.NET Identity membership system, which works great locally on my pc and not after the upload.

I already have one database with one connection string to that database (BicycleWorldShop2). Should I publish ASPNETDB.mdf as a second database and add a second connection string in web.config file?  How should I configure membership correctly?

This is the code of my **Web.config** file.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
  
    <globalization culture="en-IN" />

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Accounts/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
   <customErrors mode="Off" />
    

    
  <membership>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
        <providers>
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
        <providers>
           <clear/>
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
      
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    
    
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
  
  <add name="BicycleWorldShop2" connectionString="Data Source=WW-PC\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=BicycleWorldShop;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


   

</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

What should I change in my code?

Does anyone how to solve this?

Please, for any help, I waste a lot of time in  trying to solve this error!

The error:
[image]

Comment: Did you install SqlServer on that VM?

Comment: I published the website  to the  smarterasp.net  host. Reading the data from the published database BicycleWorldShop2 works ok, but the problem is just with authentication. The users data is stored to the ASPNETDB.mdf database, which is automatocally created in Visual studio with membership identity.

Comment: Your membershiprovider is depended on `connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"` which doesn't seem to lead to a valid instance. Add an extra connection string in your web.config that points to a catalog with the membership stuff in it.

Comment: first of all change `Data Source=WW-PC\SqlExpress`, to `Data Source=localhost`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to backup ASPNETDB.mdf and restore as a separate database on the hosting server. Then create second connectionstring under `<connectionStrings>` web.config section.

Lastly, update the `connectionstringName` property on membership, profile and roleManager providers.

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="SecondConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
```

**Alternate Approach for adding ASPNETDB Object to same database**

On your computer, type `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\` in run command and then go to v4.0... folder. In this folder, you will find T-SQL script files for creating Membership, Profile and Role schema. You will require to execute the scripts on your hosting provider database.

You will need to first execute the `InstallCommon.sql` for creating the common tables. Then you execute the following scripts.

1. InstallMembership.sql
2. InstallProfile.SQL
3. InstallRoles.sql

Note: All above mentioned scripts will assume that you have database named `aspnetdb` so you will require to open each sql file in text editor and then change the following lines of code to match your database name:

```
SET @dbname = N'aspnetdb'
USE [aspnetdb]
```

**P.S**
Do you really need `AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider`? Also, add `<clear/>` in membership and profile providers section

Comment: I don't really need AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider. I am using smarterasp.net free hosting plan and it's allowed creating only one database with one connection string. Is it possible to add two .mdf files with two different connection strings into the same database from smarterasp.net? Your idea looks optimistic, but the way to solve the problem using smarterasp.net looks a little bit unavailable.

Comment: @ZoranZoki What you can do is open your ASPNETDB.mdf using server explorer or attach .mdf file to sqlexpress. Next generate t-sql script for database schema (tables and stored procedures) and then execute that script on hosting provider database to replicate the Membership, Role and Profile schema

Comment: It didn't work for me. Your idea is to merge the databases. ASPNETDB.mdf database should automatically be created to the App_Data folder. Meanwhile i got details from the error suggestions, and thats are: Sql Server Express must be installed on the machine.
The process identity for the web server account must have a local user profile. See the readme document for details on how to create a local user profile for both machine and domain accounts. How can I check is sql express   installed on hosting machine and does the process identity for the web server account  have a local user profile?

Comment: @ZoranZoki I have added an alternate approach section in the answer. Check if that solves your problem